# ROS2 plan a trajectory without mapping (without lidar)

Tags: navigation, odometry, mapping, planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, first of all, for a little bit of context, i'm using ros2 foxy with ubuntu 20.04 and gazebo 11.
I'm still learning how everything works together so, if i'm saying something wrong, i would really appreciate to be corrected !

I have a robot defined within a urdf file, with plugins to work properly in gazebo. My robot spawn correctly, i can control it with teleop_twist_keyboard and the /tf odom -> base_link and base_link -> [other parts of my robot] are published correctly.
As odometry sources I am using differential drive encoder and an absolute location plugin in gazebo (gazebo_ros_p3d) and I have an IMU.
My robot spawn in a gazebo world that is just a planar ground with **no obstacles**

Now I just want to be able to say to my robot something like "go to x=10 and y=12" in an empty map, I don't need to map my environment (as i believe it will be hard with my available sensors anyway).
The problem I am facing is that in tutorial like https://navigation.ros.org/setup_guides/sensors/setup_sensors.html they tends to use lidars which i can't use.
From what i understood I have to publish the map -> Odom transform in order to go further but everything i found used lidars to publish it.

Now if anyone could give me some hints in where to look at, that would be wonderful !

On a side note, my robot have a trailer (for now i'm doing as if it wasn't here) but if you happens to have some documentation on path planning with a trailer I would greatly appreciate !

Thank you anyone who took the time to ream me, if you want me to add anything just tell me !

Would you have a tutorial I could follow with

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400737/ros2-plan-a-trajectory-without-mapping-(without-lidar)/) by [Bastian2909](https://answers.ros.org/users/102337/bastian2909/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2022-05-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `map->odom` is responsible for compensating for sensor drift, and also for locating the robot starting location in a map. If you have no drift and do not care about absolute coordinates, feel free to provide a static identity transform between map and odom (`ros2 run tf2_ros static_transform_publisher 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 map odom`).

---

Originally posted by [Per Edwardsson](https://answers.ros.org/users/79869/per-edwardsson/) with karma: 501 on 2022-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bastian2909](https://answers.ros.org/users/102337/bastian2909/) on 2022-05-18**:
This is exactly what i needed, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you do not have a map and obstacles then there isn't really a need for planner but just a controller ?

A while ago I was working on exactly same thing as you described, given current pose, navigate to pose X.
I wrote a ROS2 action server and client named `navigate_to_pose`, check it out  [here](https://github.com/NMBURobotics/ros2_python_demos). From the README of the repo ;

```
It is suggested you get grasp of ROS Actions in order to test and understand navigate_to_pose action interface provided in ros2_demo_python_nodes/ros2_demo_python_nodes/nav_to_pose_action_server.py.
THe purpose of this action node is to drive a robot to a certain pose (hence navigate_to_pose), It is required that you have a valid tf tree, depending on your localization setup you should have either in map or odom frame to base_link transforms, modify ros2_demo_python_nodes/ros2_demo_python_nodes/helpers.py with correct frame id (either map or odom) in the get_curr_robot_pose function.
To test the actions, source your workspace and do;
ros2 launch ros2_demo_python_nodes start_nav2pose_action.launch.py
In a separate terminal;
ros2 run ros2_demo_python_nodes nav_to_pose_action_client
For this to succeed, you do need a complete tf transform from odom/map to base_link so that robot can know its current position and navigate itself towards the goal. You can change the goal pose in ros2_demo_python_nodes/ros2_demo_python_nodes/nav_to_pose_action_client.py to send robot to different pose.
```

---

Originally posted by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) with karma: 819 on 2022-05-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1